# Django DeleteView without confirmation template

Tags: python, django

I am using Django DeleteView in a template and I've created a url & view.
Is it possible to skip the process of loading the _confirm_delete template and just post the delete immediately.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`DeleteView` responds to `POST` and `GET` requests, `GET` request display confirmation template, while `POST` deletes instance.

You can send `POST` request, without confirmation with form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url "your_delete_url_name" %}">
   {% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

If you do not want to have a link instead form button, use some javascript to make invisible form, that will be submitted on link click.

It is not good practice to use `GET` request for updating or deleting, but if you really insist you can shortcut `get` method in your class view to `post`, ie:

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In Django 4.x.x it seems required to also add:
```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.delete()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 21):

Or you can redefine `get()` method in your `DeleteView`:

```
class YourDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = YourModel
    success_url = '<success_url>'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But be careful with that, ensure that this doesn't affect other functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `get()` method to behave exactly like the `delete()` method:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

See CCBV here: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the next parameter. In your return response, make sure that the dictionary that you pass in is has something like this : `{ 'next': '/<your_path_here>}/' }`, make sure you commit the changes before adding the `next` parameter. You might want to change your view's `get` and `post` functions.

Comment: I don't have any get or post views, everything generate with the DeleteView

Comment: Okay then, well I do not think you can change it without changing your `post` function, and there is no way to do this as of 1.5 (to the best of my knowledge) looking at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#deleteview. If you do not know how to use `get()` and `post()` functions inside CBVs, then I suggest you learn about them.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could only allow HTTP request method `delete` by routing the request directly to the `delete` method of your class.

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    http_method_names = ['delete']

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # safety checks go here ex: is user allowed to delete?
        if request.user.username != kwargs['username']:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        else:
            handler = getattr(self, 'delete')
            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        success_url = str(reverse_lazy('post:user_home', kwargs={'username': username}))
        return success_url
```

Let's say your URL looks like this:

```
path('posts/delete/<int:pk>/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
```

For clarity why this works, you have to analyze the `post` and `delete` methods.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
    success URL.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

`post` just calls `delete` and `delete` gets the object and success URL, deletes the object, then redirects to the success URL you provided. `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'` is why I showed the `<int:pk>` part in the URL.

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is override the `get_success_url` method of your delete view. Then it will directly delete the object from the DB. Eg:

```
class YourView(DeleteView):
    model = YourModel

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('your_redirect_view')
```

Comment: this answer did not response the question